# different navigation bar background color between iOS 10 & iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

I'm setting my navigation bar color to `#479F46` , in iOS 10 it shows as `#5DA15D` but in iOS 11 it is showing as `#4D9D4E`

- what am I doing wrong?
- and how to solve this?

Code I use in app delegate

```
func setupNavigationController() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.colorWithHexString(hexStr: "479F46")
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white  
    let textAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
}
```

**EDIT 1**

I was using `isTranslucent = false` for my navigation controller object,

```
nvc?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

but that seemed to not suffice, I added `UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false`
as suggested by llb

and now both view OS versions show the color as `#4D9D4E`

I need them both to show up as `#479F46`

[image]

Comment: Assuming translucency *isn't* the issue, what does iOS 12 show?

Comment: There could be a bug in your `colorWithHexString`. Who knows what it does? You didn't show it.

Comment: I missed one more thing. You should also setup `UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = <Your color>` and remove `barTintColor`, as @matt suggested.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of translucency. Set it to false. Also, as @matt suggested, do not use `barTintColor`. Set `backgroundColor` instead.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = <Your color>
```

Comment: Since this *might not* be the issue, why post it as an answer? Why not ask it in a comment?

Comment: Fixed the answer. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Do not attempt to use the `barTintColor` if you want complete control over a navigation bar's color. The tint color is a *tint*. You want to dictate the *actual color*.

There is only one way to do that. *No* `barTintColor`, *no* translucency. Then give the navigation bar a background image consisting of a rectangle of the desired color.

Example:

```
let sz = CGSize(20,20)
let c = // some UIColor
let r = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:sz)
self.navbar.setBackgroundImage( r.image { ctx in
    c.setFill()
    ctx.fill(CGRect(origin:.zero, size:sz))
}, for:.any, barMetrics: .default)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's related to the color profile, make sure you are using the correct one

[image: xcode color profiles]

check this article for more details:

https://lembergsolutions.com/blog/how-get-right-color-ios-detailed-instruction